# How to correctly handle Ubuntu One questions

Tags: discussion, support, cleanup

**Tl;dr: What is going on with all the unanswered Ubuntu One questions on the site?**

I have come across a few Ubuntu One questions during the clean up like "cannot sysc", "folders missing", "logs me out" and such. Some have Windows related questions too.

What is the correct or proper answer given in these situations?

I see this as more of a Canonical issue. They have their cloud issues and storage problems. They allow purchasing of applications and responsible for the safe keeping of users files.

They have their own support page http://www.ubuntu.com/support

and contact information https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

The first 50 questions on the first page under "ubuntu-one" tag have 23 answers. What is happening to the rest of them? There are 951 questions tagged, and not all of them have answers. Yes, its not always possible to answer something, but there should be more of them answered.

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/942/keeping-the-ubuntu-one-tag-running-smoothly

Comment: Somewhat related. Who is on the U1 team? Why are there questions rotting without so much as a comment. If we ignore them do they disappear. I think we need ghost-busters

Answer (score 8):

Ubuntu One team follows the tag and answers when possible. From their [help page](http://one.ubuntu.com/help):

> Did you know?
>
> ## FAQs
>
> Our frequently asked questions are here to help you quickly find an answer to your question. So please have a quick look here first. If you can’t find what you are looking for here, have a look at our tutorials, jump on to our **Ask Ubuntu** forum or contact us directly.
>
> ## Community
>
> We have an enthusiastic community. Chances are if you have a problem someone from our global community can help you. **Ask Ubuntu** is the place where Ubuntu One users can ask and answer general questions. However, if you have account or payment-specific questions you will need to contact us directly.
>
> ## Contact us
>
> If you can’t find an answer on our FAQs or **Ask Ubuntu**, then please fill in our contact form and someone from the team will get in touch with you.

Emphasis my own

Ubuntu One is watched after by a few of the Ubuntu One devs. Questions revolving around sensitive information or account specific details are off-topic for the site. All other questions that fall under the current On-Topic umbrella are on-topic

Answer (score 5):

I recently contacted Ubuntu One support re just this matter.

This is their email to me:

```
Joshua Hoover
<ubuntuone-support@canonical.com>   13 March 2012 14:41
Reply-To: ubuntuone-support@canonical.com

Hi,

The best place to direct people to for support is this page:

https://one.ubuntu.com/help/

You can point out the FAQs, Tutorials, U1 status page and finally the
contact form you used to contact us. :)

FAQs - https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/
Tutorials - https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/
Status - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status
Contact Ubuntu One support - https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/

We don't recommend pointing people to the Ubuntu One wiki as it needs A
LOT of clean up. We hope to get to that soon.

I would only suggest pointing people to file bugs if it seems like
they're problem is a bug and not a request for help. We (Ubuntu One
support) can help the user determine if the problem is a bug or not and
file one on their behalf if it is a bug.

Thanks!

Joshua Hoover
```

Thus Ask Ubuntu is the place where Ubuntu One users can ask and answer general questions. However, account and payment-specific questions you will need to contact support directly.

Comment: guess I volunteer to cut and paste 951 answers...OMG

Comment: @BlueXrider Please do not do that.

Comment: off-beat humour. wouldn't attempt to

Answer (score 4):

If we do support Ubuntu One here, we should say so somewhere in our FAQ to avoid confusion.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/264235/ubuntuone-getting-information-please-wait-forever-on-windows-8-64bit

New users might not be aware of it being one of the *"Services provided by Ubuntu"*.

It could be as little as such:

> - Services provided by Ubuntu (e.g. Ubuntu One)

Comment: I agree that we should probably clarify this in the FAQ, but we should make sure to say something that clarifies it beyond what we already have ("Ask Ubuntu is a questions and answers site for Ubuntu-related questions."). "Services provided by Ubuntu" wouldn't help. What does that mean? It sounds like it's referring to daemons running in Ubuntu. Even if you clarify the meaning further, this would probably be wrong. We *don't* support many such services. If we decide to clarify the FAQ, we should just list "Ubuntu One," or give it and other examples.

Comment: That is a good example question, let me test by going to turn on my Windows 8.... wait I don't have windows 8! It should say in the faq that it supports the services when ran on their supported OS's ex. "Ubuntu services that run on other supported operating systems (e.g. Ubuntu One, on Windows, Mac, ect.)"