# Why are about Ubuntu paid services closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have had questions explicitly permitted, and certainly not prohibited by the FAQ closed multiple times. The most recent one, related to Ubuntu One [(which can be found here)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235633/billing-and-music-store-delivery-problems-in-ubuntu-one)

Is permitted in the FAQ:

- Services provided by Ubuntu
- Any question not mentioned below or here are great! There are no "dumb" questions!

It seems to me that it was closed based on personal preferences rather than any legitimate reason. Why are people so strict regarding closing potentially legitimate questions and is there any recourse?

Also, why are close reasons not being explained via comment? Many people new to Ubuntu are asking questions and I think close votes should at least be explained to help users ask better questions in the future.

Is there a legitimate reason why my post was closed?

Thank You.

Comment: Reading your closed question, my first thought was 'contact the bank'. If you have an issue that you contacted Canonical about, and that contact attempt wasn't replied to within about 10 days, it would be correct to pursue this through your bank (assuming you used a payment card), rather than the vendor. Vendors are far less likely to ignore a bank making an inquiry, and this has gotten me better results in the past. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, tbh it was just $2 though. I just don't want it to happen again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your post was closed because it's a long standing [policy that we just can't assist with "Ubuntu Paid services"](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2819/41) (we're just a community of users who support each other with the occasional Canonical team contributing to their areas of expertise). This isn't explicitly stated in the FAQ because we don't get many of them I can recall 10 in the past two years. As such this is why the question was closed.

It appears you got an answer, which is great, and hopefully this has been resolved for you now. If this continues to be an issue we can consider amending the FAQ to include Ubuntu paid services. The reason you don't typically find *everything* listed in the FAQ is because then the FAQ would be even longer and the chances of a user actually reading it lessens.

Comment: If they are prohibited by an "unspoken rule," I feel that the rule should be documented, especially when it's not even noted in a comment or anything. I would also like to note that I said in the post that other mediums of communication had failed. Lastly, while the underlying issue is a paid service, I asked for a means of contact... which does not require internal knowledge of the paid service to provide. It's frustrating to have questions closed for such reasons and, quite frankly, if I didn't know better I'd think the Ubuntu community quite unfriendly. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Although I will say that no, it has not been resolved. PART of the question has, but the billing issue has not, hence my frustration.

Comment: This is documented [on this meta site](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2819/41)

Comment: Unfortunately, for billing you're going to have to contact them. The user who answered appears to work for Canonical, commenting and pressing him for answers would probably be your next best move.

Comment: @Razick I would also note that while Stack Exchange works really well for technical support, it is not a way for companies to outsource their entire customer support channel. Canonical has been exemplary in providing appropriate services in the correct forum, but it's a bit difficult to enumerate *all* the ways users can find themselves in the wrong place. That's why we have a vocal and friendly community to help when things *don't* go as expected. Such *just-in-time* learning is preferable to pages of rules most never read. I hope you found the ultimate resolution satisfactory. Take care.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thank you, and I do agree with your comment on Just-in-time learning; it would have been fine, had it been explained via comment instead of just closed for what seemed like no reason. I hope you understand, thanks for your help.